# Laravel Constraining Eager Loading all table data

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have two model `News` and `Category` in one to many relationship.

**News.php**

```
public function newsCategory()
{
  return $this->belongsTo(Category::class, 'category');
}
```

Now I'm trying to get all the news with a specific category as follows

```
$news = News::select('id', 'heading', 'body', 'image', 'category', 'created_at')
    ->with(['newsCategory' => function ($query) {
     $query->where('title', 'international');
}])->get();

dd($t->toArray());
```

But its printing all the news, as follows
[image]

Laravel version : 7.30

Doc ref: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads

Answer (score 1):

Use `whereHas`

```
$news = News::select('id', 'heading', 'body', 'image', 'category', 'created_at')
        ->with(['newsCategory'])
        ->whereHas('newsCategory',function ( $query){
            $query->where('title', 'international');
        })
        ->get();
```

Ref: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence

Comment: whereHas is an easy solution but it's very slow for huge database :( join can improve performace.

Comment: then what's the use of the ref I attached in question ?

Comment: @OsmanRafi it's for eager loading query means to filter `newsCategory` for every News not for filtering `News`